# Styled Components: Change color of text due to conditon

Tags: jsx, styled-components

I have a table that renders out the string withdraw if the transaction amount is <= 0 else deposit.

How do I get the text color to change on this condition?

I know I need to use props, but can't seem to work it out?

jsx:

```
     <TransactionType>
     {transaction.amount <= 0 ? "withdraw" : "deposit"}
     </TransactionType>
```

Styled component:

```
export const TransactionType = styled.div<ITransactionType>`
color: ${(prop) => (prop.TransactionType ? "red" : "green")};
```

`;

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
<TransactionType type={transaction.amount <= 0 ? 'withdraw' : 'deposit'} >
  {transaction.amount <= 0 ? "withdraw" : "deposit"}
</TransactionType>
```

```js
export const TransactionType = styled.div<ITransactionType>`
color: ${({ type }) => (type === 'withdraw' ? "red" : "green")};
```

I renamed your prop to type for improved readability, but the concept is the same. And used destructing of the props argument to get type directly accessible.